# Is there a text editor that will auto expand custom letter combinations?

Tags: editor

I would like predetermined combinations of type to automatically change
after hitting the space bar.  For example if I type `lwt` and hit space
it will automatically change it to `learnwptheme`.

These combinations would be set up by the user.

Does such a creature exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the Mac: TextExpander.

It gives auto expanding capabilities to all applications by using accessibility
features.  So far it is exactly what I was looking for.  It even allows you to
specify where the cursor is placed after the expansion.